# Is this ? ternary operation legal?

Tags: c++, arduino, conditional-operator

I'm no expert, but I do like to learn and understand. With that in mind I wrote the following in the Arduino IDE:

```
lockout[idx] ? bulb[idx].off() : bulb[idx].on();
```

to replace this:

```
if (lockout[idx]) bulb[idx].off(); else bulb[idx].on();
```

`lockout[]` is an array of `bool`, and `bulb[]` is an array of a class, with .`off` and `.on` methods.

I've looked around for examples and never seen this usage of the `?` ternary operator. And what I've read seems to say that this should not work.

But it does compile. So is this in fact legitimate C++?

Comment: That works as long as off() and on() return something (not void) and the two values are compatible.  Usually the output of a ternary is used somehow (like being assigned to a variable or something).  It isn't idiomatic.

Comment: This does not mean you should actually use it this way.  This is ugly, misleading, and can create problems down the track.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Why should off() and on() return something? OP is not assigning the return value to anything

Comment: @offtkp no `?` does not just expand to `if else`.  There are some subtle differences involving calaculating the return type that could catch you off guard.  There are few cases where C++ "expands" to other C++; the only a "real" one I know is `for(:)` loops.  The other cases (lambdas, template more specialized, etc) are full of fudge words in the standard.  Meanwhile, `?:` is not defined in terms of `if else`.  Now, what you said is a **useful lie**, but you should try to be clear about that when you make such useful lies.

Comment: @Offtkp — that’s a very misleading characterization of what `?:` does. It’s an **expression**, so it has a value. `if … else …` is a **statement**. It does not have a value. An expression and a statement are fundamentally different things.

Comment: Compiler bugs aside, if a C++ compiler successfully compiles it often turns out to be legal C++ (although it may have undefined behaviour).   That said, `lockout[idx] ? bulb[idx].off() : bulb[idx].on()` is definitely a valid expression if `lockout[idx]` can be converted to a numeric type, and if `bulb[idx].off()` and `bulb[idx].on()` are both valid and return the same type.

Comment: Just curious: why not add a `set()` method to the bulb class? Then you can avoid `?:` and `if-else` altogether: `bulb[idx].set(!lockout[idx]);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - That's a great suggestion. Though of limited use in this program, it would be a good general addition to the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is legitimate C++.  While that operator is commonly called the *ternary operator*, it is called the *conditional operator* in the C++ standard, and it is defined in the section named "expr.cond".

The C++ standard explicity says it is OK for both the second and third operands to have type `void`.  So the standard writers knew that people might want to use this operator as a short way to write `if` statements, like you are doing.

If the types of the second or third operands are not `void`, then the standard says "an attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other" and it goes into detail about what that means.

For reference, the version of the C++ standard I am referring to is N4296, so it's a little old but I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 5):

If it compiles, it is probably well-formed code. The compiler would issue an error message if the ternary operator could not be used with those operands on account of their type. The fact that there's no such error message suggests that there is no such problem with your code.

However, under some conditions, use of the ternary operator can result in possibly unintended copying.

If both the `on` and `off` methods return `void` (or, say, `bool`) there won't be any issue of copying, and the code will work as expected: if `lockout[idx]` is true then `bulb[idx].off()` will be evaluated, otherwise `bulb[idx].on()` will be evaluated. Only one of the two alternatives will be evaluated, just like what would happen with the `if` statement.

Generally, the ternary operator is used when you need the result to be an expression. Otherwise, writing the code using an `if` statement is usually more readable.